# css flex-box wrap but avoid region

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div that uses flex and wraps the items...

```
#container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The items wrap to the next row when they reach the end of the container. I need a region which the items will also wrap around. Here is an example of what I want...

[image]

The items(grey) wrap the the next row when they reach the region(red).

I am wondering if this possible to do using flex-box.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: What other information would help?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this proof-of-concept which uses [`CSS Grid Layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). You can *skip* a region in the *grid* by using a *pseudo* element that is *empty* and is *explicitly* placed to create the effect that wrapped elements flow around it.

See demo below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, [col-start] 1fr);
}

.grid>* {
  background-color: green;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  grid-row: 1; /* row 1 */
  grid-column: 4/7; /* skip columns 4 to 6 */
  border: 1px dashed #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but using flex-box allows for the div to all be different sizes and not need to align with the grid.

Comment: The divs can be *different sizes* here too... maybe you are looking for a *masonary* layout... anyway with `flexbox` you won't be able to *span* multiple rows *just like the red box spanning rows* in the example image that you have provided...