# Wrapping around element in magazine layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to create a magazine kind of layout with an image in the top-right corner and elements (text, boxes, images) on the left side. The challenge is that elements below the image should take up the full width.

I tried

```
float: right
```

and while this wraps the other elements around the image, it does not allow the elements to fill up the available width.

Also tried flexbox but cant seem to find out how to use it properly for this case.

Example:

[image: Ex1]

When the image is higher:

[image: Ex2]

And a codepen:
https://codepen.io/dnote/pen/dLWJzd

Comment: Is it correct that you want row 2 to change width depending on the image height that is automatic based on the relation to the set width? I that case I think you would need to resolve it using javascript and not pure css.

Comment: maybe you need a *masonry layout* - here's [a question using css grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704224/css-flex-box-wrap-but-avoid-region/54705925#54705925) - but not a *dynamic* layout as yours...

Comment: @kukkuz, the masonry layout you mention is not gonna work, as a grid has fixed cell sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work by using flex-box in the end, but in a different way than I expected, and I'm not quite sure it's a "legal" solution.

Seems that flex items fill up the horizontal space in their (non-flex) parent.

I had to wrap my left elements in a div and set the display property of every element to flex.

```
#leftContent > * {
  display: flex;
}
```

https://codepen.io/dnote/pen/zXPmQZ